# Issue converting Matlab sparse() code to numpy/scipy with csc_matrix()

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm a bit of a newbie to both Matlab and Python so, many apologies if this question is a bit dumb...

I'm trying to convert some Matlab code over to Python using numpy and scipy and things were going fine until I reached the sparse matrix that someone wrote. The Matlab code goes like:

```
unwarpMatrix = sparse(phaseOrigin, ceil([1:nRead*nSlice*nPhaseDmap]/expan), 1, numPoints, numPoints)/expan;
```

Here's my python code (with my thought process) leading up to my attempt at conversion. For a given dataset I was testing with (in both Matlab and Python):

nread = 64
nslice = 28
nphasedmap = 3200
expan = 100
numpoints = 57344

Thus, the length of phaseorigin, s, and j arrays are 5734400 (and I've confirmed the functions that create my phaseorigin array output exactly the same result that Matlab does)

```
#Matlab sparse takes: S = sparse(i,j,s,m,n)
#Generates an m by n sparse matrix such that: S(i(k),j(k)) = s(k)

#scipy csc matrix takes: csc_matrix((data, ij), shape=(M, N))

#Matlab code is: unwarpMatrix = sparse(phaseOrigin, ceil([1:nRead*nSlice*nPhaseDmap]/expan), 1, numPoints, numPoints)/expan;
size = nread*nslice*nphasedmap

#i would be phaseOrigin variable
j = np.ceil(np.arange(1,size+1, dtype=np.double)/expan)

#Matlab apparently treats '1' as a scalar so I should be tiling 1 to the same size as j and phaseorigin
s = np.tile(1,size)

unwarpmatrix = csc_matrix((s,(phaseorigin, j)), shape=(numpoints,numpoints))/expan
```

so when I try to run my python code I get:

```
ValueError: column index exceedes matrix dimensions
```

This doesn't occur when I run the Matlab code even though the array sizes are larger than the defined matrix size...

What am I doing wrong? I've obviously screwed something up... Thanks very much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is; Python indexes start from `0`, whereas Matlab indexes start from `1`. So for an `array` of size `57344`, in Python first element would be `arr[0]` and last element would be `arr[57343]`.

You variable `j` has values from `1` to `57344`. You probably see the problem. Creating your `j` like this would solve the problem:

```
j = np.floor(np.arange(0,size, dtype=np.double)/expan)
```

Still, better to check this before using...

Comment: Hmm... I don't think that's the problem I'm having because len(j) = 5734400 (which is what I want), and I do want j[0] = 1

Comment: @NJM: Length of `j` is not the problem, but `max(j) = 57344`. `j` holds the column information, and if by "1" you mean the *first column*, then you certainly would want `j[0]=0` **in Python**. Check this link for differences between Python (numpy & scipy) and Matlab: http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying now. It looks like I may need to look over my phaseorigin variable as well since the max() of it seems to be 57344.00 as well. Thanks.